# Default access modifier in Java should I always declare it?

Tags: java

I am writing a list data structure, and I wanted to know, Is it always necessary to declare 'public', take the sample code...

```
public class LinkedList {

    public LinkedList() {

    }

    public class Node() {

        public Node() {

        }
    }

}
```

Or would you prefer this? Is there a standard on which style to use?

```
class LinkedList {

    LinkedList() {

    }

    class Node() {

        Node() {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default access modifier is package-private. Meaning to make a class public, you have to actually declare it as public. Otherwise you limit access to the package.

This is with the exceptions of declarations *inside* an interface. I.e. methods declared in interfaces have public as the default modifier. But for interface declaration, classes, methods, fields, enums, and @interfaces, package private is the default access modifier when none is declared.

Comment: Is this for methods and classes? If I'm writing single files for demonstration purposes is it  necessary to include the modifier every time?

Comment: It's for methods and classes. Same with interfaces and enums. Though, for interfaces, the default access modifier is public and not package-private. But for everything else, the default modifier is package-private. As long as you have all the files in the same package, you don't need a modifier.

Comment: So if I'm wiring a LinkedList demonstration to show my friend, should I include public or should I omit it?

Comment: If it's a demonstration, assuming it's all in the same package, you can omit it. if there's a plan to use it outside the package later, just use public right away.